# Macro expansion in C++

Tags: c++, macros

How can I define a macro (or a workaround for this) where the parameter is at the beginning of the line?

```
#define SINGLETON_IMPLEMENTATION(className) \
    ##className* ##className::instance_ = NULL;
```

This give a compiler warning (GCC 3.2.3): " '##' cannot appear at either end of a macro expansion"

Comment: Only place on the entire web I could find anything about this lol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`##` is the concatenation operator; the compiler is just complaining about that.
You cannot concatenate a token without something before it, i.e. at the beginning of the macro expansion; just try to remove the `##` at the beginning of the second line.
Also the second `##` seems wrong. If you just want to initialize a singleton pointer, remove both `##`s from your macro.

Answer (score 13):

You only need ## to append a parameter to another string.  Your macro can be recast as

```
#define SINGLETON_IMPLEMENTATION(className) \
    className* className::instance_ = NULL;
```

Comment: ah of course - rather embarrassing... this was driving me crazy!